# jsonwebtoken error: TypeError: option expires is invalid

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, express-jwt

I got this error whilie creating a token using json web token, I couldn't fix it:

> TypeError: option expires is invalid

Code:

```
jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET),
    {
      expiresIn: '2 days',
    }
```

I have tried to fix it by changing the value of expiresIn to 1h, 234234, but couldn't fix it

Comment: the code here doesn't match the error;  The error states `expires` is invalid, but that isn't what you have in the code here.  Please try to provide a reproducible example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way:

```
jwt.sign({ id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
  expiresIn: "2d",
})
```

Correct usage is `jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, [options, callback])`.

For [more.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

Answer (score 0):

Installing `express@4.17.1` solved that issue for me, it seemed to be an issue for the newer versions of Express.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).